# Evaluate $\lim\limits \frac{x-\sin\sin\cdots\sin x}{x^3}.$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

**Problem**

Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin\sin\cdots\sin x}{x^3},$$where $\sin\sin\cdots\sin x$ denotes **n-fold** composite sine function.

**Solution**

Consider applying Taylor's Formula with 3-order at $x=0$. We may obtain $$f_n(x)=\sin\sin\cdots\sin x=x-\frac{n}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3).\tag{*}$$ To prove this, we can apply the mathematical induction. Let $n=1,$ then $$f(x)=\sin x=x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3),$$  It's true and shows that $(*)$ holds for $n=1$. Assume that $(*)$ holds for $n=k$. Then $$\begin{align*}f_{k+1}(x)&=\sin(f_k(x))\\&=x-\frac{k}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3)-\frac{1}{6}\left(x-\frac{k}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\right)^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\\&=x-\frac{k+1}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\end{align*}.$$ This shows that $(*)$ holds for $n=k+1$. As a result, $(*)$ holds for all $n=1,2,\cdots.$
Now,let's go back to deal with the problem. $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin\sin\cdots\sin x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\left(x-\dfrac{n}{6}x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\right)}{x^3}=\frac{n}{6}.$$

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Hope to see other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is correct, and I don't know a better way.

Comment: Maybe one can deduce a formula using the L'Hopital rule. Note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\sin(x))=\cos(x) \cos(\sin(x))$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))=\cos(x) \cos(\sin(x)) \cos(\sin(\sin(x))),$$
and so on...
Then, as we know that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ maybe we can deduce your result.
I don't know if it's works correctly, it's only an idea

Comment: @nikilospuntajes But you have to differentiate $3$ times, and that's not going to be pretty.

Comment: Your proof of $(*)$ seems fine to me, but I’m curious about whence $(*)$ itself originated. Did you use a calculator of some sort and then set about proving the relation, or did you try to deduce it algebraically?

Comment: Your solution is very correct. Digging my old notes, I found that $$f_n(x)=\sin\sin\cdots\sin x=x-\frac{n}{6}x^3+\frac{n(5n-4)}{120}x^5+\mathcal{O}(x^7)$$ which shows how is approached the limit. By the way, $\to +1$.

Comment: This is separate from my other comment and relates to an approach to the problem: Since the limit is taken as $x\to0$, why not just invoke that $$f_1(x)\sim f_2(x)\sim f_3(x)\sim\cdots\sim\sin x$$ for $x$ near $0$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Answer to first comment: almost obvious once you write the Taylor exansion at order $3$. Answer to second comment: that would give you no information on $x-\sin(\dots)$: you would know it's $o(x)$, and that's not enough.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut “almost obvious” I don’t think proof by intimidation is a valid problem-solving technique.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Compute by hand the case $\sin(\sin(x))$, and you should see why I write that.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor In case the above is still not obvious, there is the mechanical way. Let $f_n(x)=\sin\dots\sin x$ with $n$ sines. It's an odd function, so it's expansion at order $3$ is $u_nx+v_nx^3+O(x^5)$. Since $f_n(x)\sim x$, $u_n=1$. Then write the Taylor formula for $\sin(f_n(x))$ to get a relation between $v_{n+1}$ and $v_n$. You'll find $v_{n+1}=v_n-\frac16$. You can check this at order $5$, and the coefficient of $x^5$ in $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $2$. If I got the recurrence on $k$ right, the coef of $x^{2k+1}$ is always a polynomial in $n$ of degree at most $k$.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to share a more tricky method with you.

Use the same notation, and assume $f_0(x) = x$, then we can prove that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - f(x)}{x^3} = \frac{1}{6}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_k(x)}{x} = 1, ~ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Thus we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_0(x) - f_k(x)}{x^3} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{f_{i - 1}(x) - f_{i}(x)}{x^3}\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^k\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_{i - 1}(x) - f_{i}(x)}{x^3}\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^k\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_{i - 1}(x) - f(f_{i-1}(x))}{(f_{i-1}(x))^3}\cdot \frac{(f_{i-1}(x))^3}{x^3}\\
&=\sum_{i = 1}^k\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f_{i - 1}(x) - f(f_{i-1}(x))}{(f_{i-1}(x))^3} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(f_{i-1}(x))^3}{x^3}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{1}{6}\\
&= \frac{k}{6}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: +1 Very nice!..

Comment: Good! Thanks.+1